# custom datasource find('list') issue

Tags: cakephp, datasource

I am creating a custom datasource and I am having problems when i request find('list'). find('all') returns perfectly what I want within my controller but find('list') just returns an empty array.

The funny thing is if I do a die(Debug($results)) in the datasource within the read function then I get my find('list') array correctly but if I return it i then get an empty array in my controller. Any ideas?

Code below:

```
public function read(Model $model, $queryData = array(), $recursive = null) {
    if ($queryData['fields'] == 'COUNT') {
        return array(array(array('count' => 1)));
    }

    $this->modelAlias = $model->alias;
    $this->suffix = str_replace('Flexipay', '', $model->alias);

    if(empty($model->id)){
        $this->url = sprintf('%s%s%s', $this->sourceUrl, 'getAll', Inflector::pluralize($this->suffix));
    }

    $r = $this->Http->get($this->url, $this->config);

    if($r->isOk()){
        $results_src = json_decode($r->body, true);

        if(is_array($results_src)){

            //$this->find('list');
            if($model->findQueryType == 'list'){
                return $this->findList($queryData, $recursive, $results_src);
            }

            //$this->find('all');
            foreach($results_src['PortalMandantenResponses']['portalMandantenResponses'] as $r){
                $results[] = $r;
            }

            if(!empty($results)){
                $e =  array($model->alias => $results);
                return $e;
            }
        }
    }else{
        //
    }
    return false;
}
```

My response from die(debug(array($model->alias => $results);

```
(int) 0 => array(
    'Mandant' => array(
        'ns2.id' => (int) 79129,
        'ns2.name' => 'company a'
    )
),
(int) 1 => array(
    'Mandant' => array(
        'ns2.id' => (int) 70000,
        'ns2.name' => 'company b'
    )
),
```

Controller Code is here:

```
    public function test2(){
    //$a = $this->User->find('list');
    //die(debug($a));
    $this->loadModel('Pay.Mandant');
    $a = $this->Mandant->find('list', array('fields' => array('ns2.systembenutzernr', 'ns2.systembenutzernrBezeichnung')));
    die(debug($a));
}
```

Comment: Soso, ein Anwalt ;) My guess is that you are somehow overwriting your return value. See if that is the issue... If not, I will take a look at it tomorrow

Comment: also: `find('all') returns perfectly what I want`  - why not use it then?

Comment: When i pr() before the return value then I get a reponse but if I take out the pr and die, then in my controller I get an empty array, wierd - I have added the response into my original post.

Comment: I need find('list') for my dropdown select

Answer (score 0):

use,

```
$a = $this->Mandant->find('list', array('fields' => array('ns2.systembenutzernr', 'ns2.systembenutzernrBezeichnung')));
$this->set(compact('a'));

You can use $a for the dropdown creation in view file.
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem writing my custom model though I don't know if the cause in your case is the same, though you should probably look in the same place.

in Model.php there is a function _findList($state, $query, $results), my issue was the fields you specify in the find() call must match the $results structure exactly, otherwise at the end of the _findList() function the call to:

```
Hash::combine($results, $query['list']['keyPath'], $query['list']['valuePath'], $query['list']['groupPath'])
```

returns the empty array. The keyPath of {n}.MODELNAME.id, etc must match the name of the model specified in $results, for example

```
[0] => ['MODELNAME'] = array()
[1] => ['MODELNAME'] = array()
```

In my case my keyPath and valuePath had a different value for MODELNAME than in the results array

Hope that helps